# Cosmological constant phase transition?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, cosmological-constant

I recently watched at a talk by Cumrum Vafa in which he stated that the cosmological constant allows us to define a time-scale $T_\Lambda=1/\sqrt{E_\Lambda}$. The time scale of this time is about 10¹¹ years, or about 10 times the current age of the Universe. Can we know what this time scale is and if it is a instability our Universe will suffer at that point? Of course, he was talking about the fate of the Universe, but I believe we don't know what is the meaning of that scale. Any hint? Is a vacuum decay necessarily?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a universe dominated by a cosmological constant, in this case [Friedmann's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations) first equation becomes

$$
\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^2 = \frac{\Lambda c^2}{3}
$$

Whose solution is

$$
a(t) \sim e^{t/T_\Lambda}
$$

where

$$
T_\Lambda = \left(\frac{3}{c^2\Lambda}\right)^{1/2}\sim \Lambda^{-1/2}
$$

Now the problem is what is actual value of $\Lambda$. If we use [Plank's](http://www.ctc.cam.ac.uk/news/130322_newsitem.php) 2015 results ($\Lambda\sim10^{-52}$ m$^{-2}$)

$$
T_{\Lambda} \approx 5\times 10^{17} ~{\rm s} \sim 10^{11} ~{\rm yr}
$$

Comment: I know all that! I did the same calculations myself...But, what happens at that time, if any?

Comment: @riemannium Sorry, perhaps I misread your question. In any case, nothing in particular will happen at that time, except the universe will increase its size by an $e$-fold